# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir un documento PDF sin que se abra el Acrobat Reader desde C#?

Tags: c#

Me gustaría saber cómo podría imprimir documentos `PDF` desde una aplicación `C#` sin que se abra
 el Acrobat Reader. Yo utilizaba el siguiente código mostrado, pero al imprimir siempre me abre el Acrobat Reader. Agradecería su ayuda.

```html
var impresora = new PrinterSettings();
impresora.PrinterName = printDialog.PrintQueue.FullName;
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     Verb = "PrintTo",
     FileName = boArchivo.UrlLocal,//put the correct path here,
     Arguments = impresora.PrinterName,
     WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
};
p.Start();
p.Close();
```

Comment: has probado con ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute=false o true; ?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba utilizando alguna de las librerias existentes,como [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) o [SharpPdf](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/). Son sencillas de manejar y evitas que el usuario necesite tener instalado el Reader.

Como otra opción, quizá podrias usar el [componente COM de Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat10_SDK_HTMLHelp&file=IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.2.html) aunque no es una opción que yo te recomendaría.

Comment: Gracias por la información deja investigo acerca de esas dos librerías.

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta es algo vieja pero estaba buscando lo mismo. Encontre algo **SIN DLLS** o Librerias de Terceros.

No hay que dar tanta vuelta, modifique el codigo encontrado para mis necesidades y buscando dentro de las propiedades de process, encontre c la forma de cerrar el programa cliente. Codigo en vb.net.

**Esta fue mi solucion**:

```
Dim Esperas As Integer = 0

    Using p As New Process
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\Test.pdf"
        p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print"

        p.Start()

        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) ' tiempo X para que el programa cliente se active he imprima

        p.CloseMainWindow() ' Cierre ventana cliente
        ' si la ventana sigue abierta, se encicla hasta cerrarla.
        While Not p.HasExited
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            Esperas += 1
            p.CloseMainWindow()
        End While
    End Using

    MsgBox("Fin del proceso # " & Esperas) ' cantidad de esperas para poder cerrar ventana cliente
```

Answer (score 1):

El mismo código pero traducido para `C#`.

```
int esperar = 0;

using (Process p = new Process()
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"temp\temp.pdf";
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";

    p.Start();
    //libreria Threading
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    p.CloseMainWindow();
    while (!p.HasExited)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        esperar++;

        p.CloseMainWindow();
    }


}
MessageBox.Show("Fin del proceso # " + esperar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día una opción es `GhostScript`, aquí te dejo información sobre esto.

Primero [aquí](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) podrás encontrar el sitio de descarga. Después verás que en [esta publicación de SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599925/how-to-print-pdf-on-default-network-printer-using-ghostscript-gswin32c-exe-she) existe una respuesta de como usarlo (De igual manera aquí te dejo el método).

```
 /// <param name="ghostScriptPath">El path donde está el archivo de GhostScript. Ejemplo "C:\Program Files\gs\gs8.71\bin\gswin32c.exe"</param>
/// <param name="numberOfCopies">Número de copias.</param>
/// <param name="printerName">Nombre de la impresora. Ejemplo \\server_name\printer_name</param>
/// <param name="pdfFileName">path del archivo pdf.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool PrintPDF (string ghostScriptPath, int numberOfCopies, string printerName, string pdfFileName) {
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo  = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.Arguments         = " -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=" + Convert.ToString(numberOfCopies) + " -sDEVICE=ljet4 -sOutputFile=\"\\\\spool\\" + printerName + "\" \"" + pdfFileName + "\" ";
    startInfo.FileName          = ghostScriptPath; 
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);

    Console.WriteLine( process.StandardError.ReadToEnd() + process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() );

    process.WaitForExit(30000);
    if (process.HasExited == false) process.Kill();


    return process.ExitCode == 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola que tal, mi pregunta es, si tengo una empresa puedo utilizarlo gratuitamente, te afirmo que el software que tengo no es comercial, si no que es de uso para uso interno. Tengo que instalar en cada máquina el GhostScript?

Comment: Hola, pues tiene una versión con licencia GNU y otra con versión comercial. En este caso puedes intentar tener el GhostScript en una carpeta compartida. Con respecto a un pago por el uso, no sabría decirte como funciona o sí tuvieras que compar la licencia o no